# How do I make a 2 point corner with a rectangle and keep the right thickness?

Tags: c++, math, sfml, angle

I'm trying to draw a dialog box with sfml and I'm using a VertexArray with quads. I want it to have a corner with 2 points like in this image:

[image]

Could someone help me with the math on how to get the length of A? Or maybe someone has a suggestion to do it in a different way in sfml?

Comment: For the width of the grey bar to be the same as the width of the black bar, the smallest angle in the pink triangle would have to be half of 45.  So A/Th = TAN(22.5)  right?

Comment: Ow god is that angle really 22.5? I wasn't sure, but thanks.

Comment: Evident if you reflect the pink triangle along its hypotenuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking is called the *miter angle*.  And the miter angle is just half of the corner angle.

[image]

See [this interactive diagram](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/geyukbut) (at Geogebra)

By trigonometry, the ratio A/Th = TAN(angle/2).

A = Th * TAN(22.5)